# ニコニコ動画のストリーミング再生

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

ニコニコ動画を再生出来るアプリを作成しようと開発をしているのですが、
Alamofireを使い
ランキング取得→動画ID取得→動画URL取得→動画ページをHEADまで行い
AVPlayerに動画URLを渡したのですが再生がされません

どうすればストリーミング再生が出来るのでしょうか

よろしくお願い致します

Answer (score 1):

ニコニコ動画の動画ファイルはRTSP over HTTPで取得できます。

「iOS RTSP」で検索するとプレイヤーライブラリがいくつかあったので、自前実装をするよりもRTSPに対応したプレイヤーを探すほうが手間が少ないかもしれません。

ただ、ニコニコ動画の動画はmp4/flv/swfの３種類があり、対応していないフォーマットの場合には、変換処理等が必要になります。（動画タイプはflashvars.movie_typeから判別できます）

Answer (score 0):

ニコニコ動画の動画はflv形式でのストリーミング配信のはずです。
なので、動画ページのURLを取得するのではなく、sm,nm等で始まる動画番号を取得して、Web APIからflvの動画情報をxmlで取得し、パースする必要があります。
詳しいAPIの仕様は下の行のURLを参照して下さい
http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%8B%E3%82%B3%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BBapi

Comment: 説明が不十分ですいませんでした。
「動画URL取得」で実はAPIから動画情報を取得しており、
一度動画ページにアクセスしないと再生できないため動画ページのURLも取得しています。